# Replace multiple words in multiple strings

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I want to replace words in a vector based on original and replacement words in another dataframe. As an example:

A vector of strings to be altered:

```
my_words <- c("example r", "example River", "example R", "anthoer river",
        "now a creek", "and another Ck", "example river tributary")
```

A dataframe of words to be replaced and the corresponding replacement words:

```
my_replace <- data.frame(
  original = c("r", "River", "R", "river", "Ck", "creek", "Creek"),
  replacement = c("R", "R", "R", 'R', "C", "C", "C"))
```

I want to replace any occurrence of one of the words in `my_replace$original` with the corresponding value in `my_replace$replacement` in the vector `my_words`. I tried using `stringr::str_replace_all()`, but it replaced all instances of the letter/word, rather than just whole words (e.g. "another" became "anotheR") which is undesirable.

psuedo code of what I want to do:

```
str_replace_all(my_words, my_replace$original, my_replace$replacement)
```

Desired output:

```
"example R", "example R", "example R", "another R", "now a C", "and another C", "example R tributary"
```

I did find a solution using a `for` loop, but given my dataset is large, the `for` loop option is too slow. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringi)

stri_replace_all_regex(my_words, "\\b" %s+% my_replace$original %s+% "\\b", my_replace$replacement, vectorize_all = FALSE)

[1] "example R" "example R" "example R" "anthoer R" "now a C" "and another C" "example R tributary"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one `sub` approach which makes just a single replacement:

```r
my_words <- c("example r", "example River", "example R", "anthoer river",
    "now a creek", "and another Ck", "example river tributary")

output <- gsub("\\b([rR])(?:iver)?\\b|\\b([cC])(?:ree)?k\\b", "\\U\\1\\U\\2", my_words, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "example R"           "example R"           "example R"
[4] "anthoer R"           "now a C"             "and another C"
[7] "example R tributary"
```

Since the replacements for all river and creek occurrences is just `R` and `C`, respectively, we can capture the first letter of each possible match and then replace using the uppercase version of those letters.

Comment: I should have given a more detailed example, with my full dataset there are 20-30 other alterative replacement codes and not all are single letters (e.g. "pond" and "Pond" become "Pnd" and "Sound" and "sounds" become "Snd"). So I need a solution that uses the values in `my_replace$replacement`., rather than relying on deleting part of the word.

Comment: @flee Well for 20-30 other target matches, you could just expand the alternation in my answer to include them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a dynamic word boundary based pattern out of the words in `my_words$original` and then use `stringr::str_replace_all` to replace with the corresponding values. Note the `original` phrases need to be sorted by length in descending order to make longer strings match first:

```r
my_words <- c("example r", "example River", "example R", "anthoer river", "now a creek", "and another Ck", "example river tributary")
my_replace <- data.frame(original = c("r", "River", "R", "river", "Ck", "creek", "Creek"), replacement = c("R", "R", "R", 'R', "C", "C", "C"))
sort.by.length.desc <- function (v) v[order( -nchar(v)) ]
library(stringr)
regex <- paste0("\\b(",paste(sort.by.length.desc(my_replace$original), collapse="|"), ")\\b")
str_replace_all(my_words, regex, function(word) my_replace$replacement[my_replace$original==word][[1]][1])
```

Output:

```
[1] "example R"           "example R"           "example R"           "anthoer R"           "now a C"             "and another C"       "example R tributary"
```

The regex will be `\b(River|river|creek|Creek|Ck|r|R)\b`, it matches any of the words inside as a whole word.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done very straightforward using `rflashtext` library:

```
my_words <- c("example r", "example River", "example R", "anthoer river",
              "now a creek", "and another Ck", "example river tributary")

my_replace <- data.frame(
  original = c("r", "River", "R", "river", "Ck", "creek", "Creek"),
  replacement = c("R", "R", "R", 'R', "C", "C", "C"))

library(rflashtext)

processor <- KeywordProcessor$new(keys = my_replace$original,
                                  words = my_replace$replacement)

processor$replace_keys(my_words)

[1] "example R"           "example R"           "example R"           "anthoer R"          
[5] "now a C"             "and another C"       "example R tributary"
```